# How to attach a task to service on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

am using CDK to create an ECS service, it get stuck at created and I throws the message

```
was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container Instances were found in your cluster. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide.
```

I can see the task definition created successfully but not attached to the service

```
const cdk = require('aws-cdk-lib');
const ec2 = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2');
const ecr = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr');
const ecs = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs');
const ecrAssets = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr-assets');
const elbv2 = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2');
const iam = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam');




const path = require('path');

class ExpressAppStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope, id, props) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create a VPC for the EC2 instance
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'Vpc', {
      natGateways: 0
    });

    // Create an Amazon ECR repository
    const repository = new ecr.Repository(this, 'ECRRepository', {
      repositoryName: 'express-app',
    });

    // Create a Docker image asset from your code directory
    const asset = new ecrAssets.DockerImageAsset(this, 'MyAsset', {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, '../../'),
      assetHashType: cdk.AssetHashType.SHORT,

      repository: repository, // Associate the asset with the repository
    });

    // Create an ECS cluster
    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'MyCluster', {
      vpc: vpc,
    });

    // Add EC2 capacity to the cluster
    cluster.addCapacity('Ec2Capacity', {
      instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t2.micro'), // Specify the desired instance type
      desiredCapacity: 1,
      minCapacity: 1,
      maxCapacity: 2,
      keyName: "elitereals"
    });

    // Create an execution role for the EC2 task definition
    const taskExecutionRole = new iam.Role(this, 'TaskExecutionRole', {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com'),
      roleName: 'ExpressAppTaskExecutionRole',
    });

    // Attach necessary policies to the execution role
    taskExecutionRole.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'));

    const serverTaskDef = new ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(this, 'ExpressECS_ServerTaskDef', {
      executionRole: taskExecutionRole

    });

    const container = serverTaskDef.addContainer('DefaultContainer', {
      containerName: 'express-app-container',
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(asset),
      memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
      logging: ecs.LogDrivers.awsLogs({
        streamPrefix: `express-app`
      }),
      environment: {
      },
      portMappings: [
        {
          containerPort: 5000,
          hostPort: 0,
        },
      ],
    });
    // Create an ECS service
    const service = new ecs.Ec2Service(this, 'MyService', {
      cluster: cluster,
      taskDefinition: serverTaskDef
    });

  }
}

module.exports = { ExpressAppStack };
```

Comment: You need to decrease your task memory or increase your instance size. not 100% of instance RAM is available for ECS tasks.

Comment: that didn't work